# PHP : Loops, arrays and sorting

Tags: php, arrays, function, loops, time

```
public function getAllEventsByDate($allEvents, $date) {
    $theEvents = array();

    foreach ($allEvents as $event) {
        if ($date == 'future' && $event['start'] > time())
            $theEvents[] = $event;
        else if ($date == 'past' && $event['stop'] < time())
            $theEvents[] = $event;
        else if ($date == 'current' && $event['start'] < time() &&
        $event['stop'] > time())
            $theEvents[] = $event;
    }

    return $theEvents;
}
```

My boss was surprised that I use every time `$theEvents[]`.

How would you do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My boss was surprised that I use every time `$theEvents[]`.  How would you do this?

I'd do it... just like that, actually.  That code seems relatively simple, straightforward and entirely unambiguous.  It's a little verbose (you could condense it into a single `if` check), but it's verbose for a purpose and is very clear.

What are your boss' concerns?

Comment: I could do in a single if, actually. But i'll keep my code, you're right it's easier. My boss just looked diagonally.

Comment: Do make sure to look at the other examples that have been posted here.  With proper formatting, doing this in a single `if` can be just as clear as your current code.  It might not be any *better*, mind you, but it's always good to know alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe code should look like this.

```
public function getAllEventsByDate($allEvents, $date) {
    $theEvents = array();

    foreach ($allEvents as $event) {
        $condition =
            ($date == 'future'  && $event['start'] > time()) ||
            ($date == 'past'    && $event['stop']  < time()) ||
            ($date == 'current' && $event['start'] < time() &&
                                   $event['stop']  > time())
        ;

        if ($condition) {
            $theEvents[] = $event;
        }
    }

    return $theEvents;
}
```

Comment: I love the assignment-from-conditional technique, this is a great example.

Answer (score 1):

Since all of your conditional branches lead to the same statement, it can be written as one if-statement (see below).

```
public function getAllEventsByDate($allEvents, $date) {
    $theEvents = array();

    foreach ($allEvents as $event) {
        if (
             ( ($date == 'future') && ($event['start'] > time()) ) ||
             ( ($date == 'past') && ($event['stop'] < time()) ) ||
             ( ($date == 'current') && ($event['start'] < time()) && ($event['stop'] > time()) )
           ) {
                 $theEvents[] = $event;
             }

        return $theEvents;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the response of Whirlpool :

```
public function getAllEventsByDate($allEvents, $date) {
    $theEvents = array();

    $condition1 = ($date == 'future'  && $event['start'] > time());
    $condition2 = ($date == 'past'    && $event['stop']  < time());
    $condition3 = ($date == 'current' && $event['start'] < time()
                                      && $event['stop']  > time());

    foreach ($allEvents as $event)
        if ($condition1 || $condition2 || $condition3)
            $theEvents[] = $event;

    return $theEvents;
}
```